# MSBuild cannot deploy to localhost ReportServer

Tags: reporting-services, deployment, msbuild

I'm trying to deploy a solution with two rptproj projects to local SSRS ReportServer:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" \ 
"C:\Users\Documents\Reports\Reports.sln" /target:Deploy /p:TargetServerUrl=http://localhost/ReportServer /p:configuration="Release" /p:Username="MYSERVER\ReportDeployer" /p:Password=sOmepAsSwoRD
```

Building of rdl files succeeds but when it attempts to deploy, it almost immediately fails with the following message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MS
Builder.targets(30,5): error :  : Could not connect to the report server http://localhost/ReportServer. Verify that t
he TargetServerURL is valid and that you have the correct permissions to connect to the report server.
```

I have verified that the ReportServer is running and that I can access it with the credentials I supply in /p:Username and /p:Password and that the user has all permissions on the root folder on the ReportServer. The reports have already been published from Visual Studio just fine many times - VS just shows the popup for credentials and then it succeeds.

I also tried wget and it successfully passes the authentication and loads the ReportServer page:

```
wget http://localhost/ReportServer --user "MYSERVER\ReportDeployer" --password sOmepAsSwoRD

--2019-03-22 23:11:19--  http://localhost/ReportServer
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authentication selected: Basic realm="localhost"
Reusing existing connection to [localhost]:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 574 [text/html]
Saving to: 'ReportServer.1'

ReportServer.1                100%[===================================================>]     574  --.-KB/s   in 0s

2019-03-22 23:11:19 (11.4 MB/s) - 'ReportServer.1' saved [574/574]
```

What's wrong with MSBuild? How do I make it work with local ReportServer?

I also tried devenv.com command line

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "C:\Users\Documents\Reports\Reports.sln" /deploy
```

with hope that it will display more detailed error information. But it seems to ignore the deploy command and outputs:

```
------ Build started: Project: Reports, Configuration: Release ------
Build Build complete
...

------ Skipped Deploy: Project: Reports, Configuration: Release ------
Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
========== Build: 2 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 skipped ==========
```

Why does it say "Build started", while if I run Deploy in Visual Studio it outputs "Deploy started" and indeed deploys the project?

How do I automate SSRS project deployment then?